# Using Dot Operator(JSTL) in Java

Tags: java, jstl, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a requirement where I need to traverse a hierarchy of Java beans and the hierarchy is different based on the starting point. What would be ideal is if I would be able to use the "dot operator" from JSTL in my Java class.

Then I can have a static map of Strings to describe my hierarchy..something like:

```
clazz1=attribute1.attribute2
clazz2=attribute3.attribute4
```

I look up which class and which attributes I need to drill down and go to the root object.

I am coding for it anyway, just checking if BeanUtils etc had such a facility already since seems to me like it can be an useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some of your code in groovy - it compiles to java bytecode so interoperates perfectly.